Stripe does not have an option to reuse data from Stripe account for onboarding process of creating a connected account
I have a platform account and i want to create connected accounts to it.
When I generate an onboarding link and when I open it and login with an existing email and password, I would expect Stripe to give me an option to prefill the information from my existing account (not a connected one, just a regular Stripe account).
What happened is that I did not get that option to prefill the info and I needed to go through the whole onboarding process filling the information (which is already present in my individual account).
Is this expected? Is there a setting that would enable this behavior or OAuth is the only option? The problem I have with OAuth is that in docs, multiple places says not to use it.

There is not a way to reuse the data collected during onboarding. However, if you already have the data collected on your end, you can pass that information / prefill the data when you create the Connected Account. The behavior you're seeing is expected.
OAuth is still supported, but it is their legacy product. It is recommended to use their Connected Onboarding and pass in the data already collected to prefill your onboarding information.

I'm able to reuse the data if i have a connected account for any platform before the onboarding process, but not if i have just a normal Stripe account (not a connected one). Which is just repeating data input on the onboarding process.
And i see users complaining for that. But we tried to avoid the legacy approach at all costs by now.

And when i say reuse the data. We don't store anything about the user account in our system, just the accountId. We want Stripe to offer us to reuse information form other account when opening the onboarding link.
